# Add dropdown on custom action bar view at left, with checkable items

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, checkbox, android-actionbar

I have a lot of problems with the development of an action bar. Here are my needs:

- I want to add a dropdown in my action bar, which is using custom view because of some custom comportment (animation for example).
- The dropdown have to be accessible from an image button (not a spinner which show a text area of the selected element).
- The image button that allow to show the dropdown have to be at the left of the action bar.
- The dropdown that appear have to contain checkable items, and, when the user check an item, the dropdown have to not be hidden (this allow the user to check multiple items at once).
- My application have to work from android 2.3 (I'm using action bar sherlock for that, I specify this because of I can't use PopupMenu on android 2.3).

I have successfully added a dropdown in my action bar by combining my custom view (actionBar.setCustomView(...)) with a menu (menuInflater.inflate(...)). I think the code of my customview is not very important, here is the code of my menu :

```
<item
    android:title="test"
    android:drawable="@drawable/dropdown_icon"
    android:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="item 1"
            android:checkable="true"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:title="item 2"
            android:checkable="true"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:title="item 3"
            android:checkable="true"/>

    </menu>

</item>
```

With this solution, I have the following problems :

- I'm not able to put the dropdown item at left (it's at the right for the moment)
- When I check an item on the dropdown list, my dropdown hide itself. I want that the dropdown keep its showing state.

How can I achieve what I want ?

P.S : As you can read, English is not my native language. These problems are difficult to explain (even in my native language), so if some sentences are not understandable, please tell me and I will try to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing the simplest thing possible: remove all the ActionBarSherlock related code and add your own views in layout and program them to animate, pop-up, show and hide.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but, if I was able to do that (create this "special" dropdown popup), the removing of the ActionBarSherlock will be useless ! I explain : my custom view hold a custom layout that contains buttons and I can do what I want on click on these buttons. So, your answer doesn't solve anything. If you show me how to create a dropdown menu at the button position, with checkable items that work as I want, and that all of that is compatible with android 2.3, I will accept the answer :-)